# chrome doesn't update site due to cached files

Tags: html, css, caching, browser

Just got a server and as I am uploading my files I noticed that Chrome has a big issue with file caching. I set the `.htaccess` to `ExpiresByType text/css "modification plus 1 month"` for CSS & JS.

If I make any change post upload to any CSS or JS file, and upload the revision, Chrome still shows the old/cached version. Other browsers like Firefox do not have this issue and show the updated version.

I am new to browser caching, what is best practice? Do I set caching to never keep CSS files? Do I have to empty the browser cache every time I want to view the website ?

Comment: the best practice is to make it cache if you didn't change the content. so you can generate a `hash` value for each file.  and the value should base on the content, if you change your content, the hash will change. have you tried to use `webpack`?  check this out https://webpack.js.org/guides/caching/

Comment: @JasonYoung have not tried it. This is for a portfolio site, so i think in the beginning there will be many changes, and in the end there will be minimal. I guess I can just set the `ExpiresByType` to 1 hour for now